# manipulate text file line by line or as a whole string?

Tags: python

```
for line in open('file.txt'):
    print(re.sub('windows', 'linux', line))
```

or

```
print(re.sub('windows', 'linux', open('file.txt').read()))
```

Which one is better? Is there any differences?
BTW. Is is a good idea to manipulate a huge string with a `regex`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Polynomial said, the second one reads the whole file into RAM, which may or may not be better.

But there is another solution:

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(re.sub('windows', 'linux', line))
```

This ensures that the file will be closed immediately after not needing it any longer.

Similiarly,

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
    print(re.sub('windows', 'linux', file.read()))
```

can be used as well.

Comment: I think this *should* be used as opposed to the original version which would leave the files opened. Or would require additional line of code. Nevertheless this is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is more readable by my standards, but will do one file read operation per line. It may be more memory efficient (each line just reallocates one buffer, vs. loading the whole file into memory), depending on the underlying .

The second one is uglier, but will be more IO efficient.

All in all, probably not much difference unless it's doing a ludicrous amount of work.